# WordPress Theme how to add HTML code to admin page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a new WP theme and I am dabbling into the admin side of things for the first time. I want to add some basic HTML to an admin page, say "edit-tags.php". Is there a hook I can use, or a way to replace this file with my own version? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to add to the edit-tags.php page? Editing pages in the admin doesn't seem like a good idea to me, but if you need to you could use the `load-{$pagenow}` hook. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/load-pagenow/